# jhipster creating microservice with sample apps.jdl causing multiple npm errors

Tags: microservices, jhipster, okta

I am trying to build sample jhipster micro service app from the blog

https://dev.to/jhipster/how-to-deploy-jhipster-microservices-on-amazon-eks-using-terraform-and-kubernetes-49a5

while generating default with `jhipster jdl apps.jdl` https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oktadev/okta-jhipster-k8s-eks-microservices-example/main/apps.jdl  causing multiple npm errors

[image]

entire logs can be accessed https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vidhya03/89fb728a0af15c3b81c8a60061b3cf5d/raw/0dd14758f7548c0c37f2be050eccd327d5e55b80/buildlogs.log

Comment: Are you running jhipster from git bash or from standard shells: Command Prompt or Powershell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the JHipster version used? Please note that there are some issues with releases 7.9.0 and 7.9.1 on Windows. So if you are using any of them, please update to 7.9.2 first. Then delete the `.npmrc` file generated on the `store` app and try running `npm install` again on the store app. That should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot deepu.  i was doing this repeating multiple times , uninstalling and installing in separate directory. finally found that inside dev container it worked , however your solution solved my case.